# Unexpected token. react-native/index.js "typeof" Error when integrating React Native Component for Deep Linking in React JS based MicroStrategy widget

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ipad, deep-linking, microstrategy

I have developed a MicroStrategy widget using a React-based framework, and it works flawlessly on various platforms. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to call the URL scheme in the MicroStrategy iPad app. Specifically, the app fails to open a specific MicroStrategy document. To address this problem, I decided to explore deep linking or the linking feature of React Native.

In my efforts to integrate the React Native component into the React JS MicroStrategy plugin, I encountered an error while generating the build. The error message reads as follows:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/index.js 14:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| // Components
> import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
| import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
| import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
 @ ./src/components/saveAll.js 22:0-45 119:21-39 127:21-36 161:21-39 169:21-36
 @ ./src/App.js 24:0-43 201:40-47
 @ ./src/ImporExcelMobile.js 10:0-24 79:56-59
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this error.
Thank you for your support and expertise in advance